Spin connection as vector and pseudo-vector meaning?
Given the Dirac equation in curved space for a massless fermion and potential A:
$$e^{\mu}_a \gamma^a (\partial_\mu + \omega^{ab}_\mu.\sigma_{ab}  + iA_\mu)\psi  = 0$$
This can be expanded out to:
$$e^\mu_a \gamma^a \partial_\mu \psi + i(\gamma^a ( B_a + i\gamma_5 C_a) +  A_a )\psi = 0$$
for certain vectors $B$ and $C$ being a vector and pseudo-vector. Separating out left-handed and right handed parts using the projection operators $1\pm \gamma_5$
$$e^\mu_a \gamma^a \partial_\mu \psi + i(\gamma^a ( (1+\gamma_5)E_a + (1-\gamma_5)\overline{E}_a) +  A_a )\psi = 0$$
Or can be written in slash notation:
$$\not e^\mu \partial_\mu \psi + i(((1-\gamma_5)\not E + (1+\gamma_5)\not\overline{E}) +  \not A )\psi = 0$$
With $E= (B+iC)/2$ a complex vector (if I have all my $i$'s correct other wise it is $E^\pm = (B\pm C)/2$ if I don't.)
This looks like the spin connection is similar to two vector fields, acting on the left and right handed particles differently. (If I have all my $i$'s correct). Or a vector field acting on the left-handed electrons and it's complex conjugate acting on the right. This is different to the electromagnetic potential which acts on both the same.
I understand the vector part since this is just saying the this potential is effectively adding to the momentum $i\partial_\mu$ which becomes $k_\mu$, I don't understand the pseudo-vector part, specifically if it violates the equivalence principle if it acts on left and right particles differently (gravity should apply equally to all particles).
I am also not sure if both the vector and pseudo vector part survive in the action $\int \Re({\overline{\psi}\gamma^a (\partial_\mu + \omega^{ab}_\mu.\sigma_{ab}  + iA_\mu)\psi})$ at first I thought one part was imaginary and would not survive (e.g. $C=0$ but I think I just miscounted my $i's$.) I expect that $B_0(r) \approx -\frac{MG}{r}$ to generate the gravitational potential when $r$ is large and probably $C$ would only be non-zero around rotating objects like a Kerr black hole.
Another way of putting the question is what is the affect of a pseudo-vector potential as opposed to a vector potential in the Dirac equation? (And do the vectors $B$ and $C$ have names in this case?)
